# Issue trying to capture webcam to picturebox with VB Net and net framework 4

Tags: vb.net, .net-4.0

I want to capture my webcam into a picturebox, I tried this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ADM1SJp0XCU) (which uses Net framework 4.5) but when I run it I get the following message:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException en Emgu.CV.dll...

I get this message even when I change the project to 4.5 or 4, but when I change it to 3.5 it works.

I tried with other examples (aforge, emgu, etc) but all of them run with Net framework 3.5 and not with Net framework 4.

Does anybody know how can I make it run?

This is the code:

```
Imports Emgu.CV
Imports Emgu.CV.Util
Imports Emgu.CV.Structure
Public Class Form1
Dim capturez As Capture = New Capture()

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim imagez As Image(Of Bgr, Byte) = capturez.QueryFrame()
    PictureBox1.Image = imagez.ToBitmap()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What version of Emgu are you using?

Comment: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images#Accessing_the_pixels_from_Mat

Comment: I´m using windows-x86 2.4.0.1717

Answer (score 0):

Add x86 file to your project, and select all files and change Copy to output directory to " copy if newer" in properties.